# How to set the default program for log4j/log4net log files?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-management, logging, file-extension

The mentioned log4j/log4net output files look like these:

- importer-log-file.log.2016-06-09
- importer-log-file.log.2016-06-10
- importer-log-file.log.2016-06-11

or

- exporter-log-file.txt.2016-06-09
- exporter-log-file.txt.2016-06-10
- exporter-log-file.txt.2016-06-11

The key is that the extension may vary, but there is one constant - an **appendix** after the filename.extension pair (the new one is generated everyday).

Is there a way to set the, let's say, Notepad++ as the default program for all the files in format **filename.extension.changable-appendix**?

Comment: This is impossible. I would stab myself if my team decided to name their log files this way.